# prevent all links in fullscreen web app to open in safari?

Tags: colorbox

I have below script that prevents links in a fullscreen-standalone web app to open in safari, this works great, but I have a colorbox script that opens a lightbox in an iframe, or it should!

Now it is opening the iframe script in fullscreen, not in an iframe in the lightbox.

So my question is, how can I change the script so it works on all links except on the one with class="iframe"? 
So that the one with class iframe work as it should.

```
(function(document,navigator,standalone) {
    // prevents links from apps from oppening in mobile safari
    // this javascript must be the first script in your <head>
    if ((standalone in navigator) && navigator[standalone]) {


        var curnode, location=document.location, stop=/^(a|html)$/i;
        document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            curnode=e.target;
            while (!(stop).test(curnode.nodeName)) {
                curnode=curnode.parentNode;
            }

            // Condidions to do this only on links to your own app
            // if you want all links, use if('href' in curnode) instead.
            if('href' in curnode && ( curnode.href.indexOf('http') || ~curnode.href.indexOf(location.host) ) ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                location.href = curnode.href;


            }
        },false);

    }

})(document,window.navigator,'standalone');
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I found the answer.
I had to change this

```
if('href' in curnode && ( curnode.href.indexOf('http') || ~curnode.href.indexOf(location.host) ) ) {
```

to this.

```
if('href' in curnode && ( curnode.href.indexOf('http') || ~curnode.href.indexOf(location.host) )&& !$(curnode).hasClass('iframe') ) {
```